# Converting QGIS feature selection into dataframe to allow plotting

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-3, geodataframe

I have a layer containing thousands of points of X,Y,Z data (sample below).

```
fid field_1 field_2 field_3
1   525146  675224  -342.1
2   525148  675224  -342.2
3   525150  675224  -342.1
4   525152  675224  -341.9
5   525154  675224  -341.8
6   525156  675226  -342.1
```

I want to manually select a subset (eg Select Features by Polygon) and then pass the selection into a script to produce a 3D point cloud. The 3D plot part works as a standalone for reading the original txt file.
What I am having trouble with is converting my QGIS selected points into a dataframe.

```
import pandas as pd

layer = qgis.utils.iface.activeLayer()
sel=layer.selectedFeatures()#[:,0]
#x = layer.selectedFeatures()[:,1]
#y = layer.selectedFeatures()[:,2]
#z = layer.selectedFeatures()[:,3]

df=pd.DataFrame({'X':sel[:,1],'Y':sel[:,2],'Z':sel[:,3]},index=sel[:,0])
```

The various #out sections are my attempts to get the correct combination of rows/columns but I either get errors or only a single point plotting.   The code below is the standalone

```
##3D graph plotting standalone code.
import plotly.express as px

##These first two lines is what I am trying to bypass by using the code above##
#df= pd.read_csv("Some_Path/input_data.txt") 
#df.columns=['X','Y','Z']

fig = px.scatter_3d(df, x='X', y='Y', z='Z',color='Z',color_continuous_scale=[(0,'violet'),(0.18,'blue'),(0.35,'lightblue'),(0.50,'green'),(0.65,'yellow'),(0.83,'orange'),(1,'red')])
    
    fig.update_yaxes(
                 scaleanchor="x",
                 scaleratio=1,
                 exponentformat='none')
    fig.update_xaxes(
                 scaleanchor="x",
                 scaleratio=1,
                 exponentformat='none')
    fig.update_layout(template="plotly_dark",title="3D Point model.") 
    fig.update_scenes(aspectratio=dict(x=2,y=2,z=0.05)) 
    fig.update_traces(marker=dict(size=2))
    fig.write_html("Some_Path/Point_Cloud.html")
```

I can just save the selection and then run the standalone script, but it would be neater to do it within QGIS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The selected data, although looking more complicated when viewed, was ready to directly go into a dataframe.

```
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px
layer = qgis.utils.iface.activeLayer()
sel=layer.selectedFeatures()

df=pd.DataFrame(sel)
df.columns=['X','Y','Z']
```

Comment: This is thanks to QGIS and many other tools supporting the Geo Interface (for existing QGIS features at least, I haven't figured out if one can easily create features from other software through it): https://gist.github.com/sgillies/2217756